# OpenCMS: Make an OR clause for validation rule

Tags: opencms

In an OpenCMS environment I have created a link object:

```
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="LinkTitle" type="OpenCmsString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="InternalLink" type="OpenCmsVfsFile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element name="ExternalLink" type="OpenCmsString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
```

This means that `LinkTitle` is always mandatory. This is correct. Given a `LinkTitle`, one (and only one) between `InternalLink` and `ExternalLink` must be provided. If I set `minOccurs="1"` for both fields doesn't makes any sense. What can I do?
It should be usefull if I could create two regex (one for `InternalLink` and one for `ExternalLink`) and than make an OR (rather than the usual AND) beetween them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested XSD option.
refer this link http://arquivo.bng-galiza.org/opencms/opencms/alkacon-documentation/documentation_xmlcontent/step5-nestedcontents.html